# inverse fft with matlab not working

Tags: matlab

I am trying to do an inverse FFT in Matlab, but I can't seem to get the inverse working correctly. Here is my code:

```
    data = [-0.0005
       -0.0004
       -0.0003
       -0.0002
       -0.0001
       -0.0000
        0.0001
        0.0001
        0.0001
        0.0002
        0.0002
        0.0002
        0.0002
        0.0002
        0.0002
        0.0002
        0.0002
        0.0002
        0.0003
        0.0004
        0.0005
        0.0006
        0.0007
        0.0009
        0.0010
        0.0011
        0.0011
        0.0012
        0.0011
        0.0011
        0.0011
        0.0010 ];    


%plot data
figure(1)
plot(data)    

%FFT
N = 100;
X = fft(data, N);
F = [-N/2:N/2-1]/N;
F = F/0.0125;

X = fftshift(X);
figure(2)
plot(F, abs( X ) )

%inverse FFT
y = ifft(X);
figure(3)
plot(F,y)
```

Figure 1 and 3 should be identical, but are not in any way. I made sure not to take `ifft` of the absolute value of `fft`, so it's not clear to me what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you shifted the spectrum using `fftshift`, you have to "unshift" the spectrum prior to taking the inverse Fourier transform

```
y = ifft(fftshift(X));
```

Comment: That was fast. When my `N` is chosen too large, the values are just set to 0. Why is that, should I not pass `N` at all then?

Comment: By default `N` is the length of your signal. If your `N` is anything larger than the length of your signal it will be zero-padded.

Comment: Do you recommend that I use the default value, or is it better that I fix it manually?

Comment: @BillyJean Yes I would use the default unless you have a good reason to do otherwise.